# Como posso ler o Docblock de um método em PHP para uma string?

Tags: php, classes

Gostaria de saber como posso ler o Docblock de um método em PHP e transformá-lo em uma string.

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte código:

```
class Stack
{
     /**
      * @return void
     */
     public function overflow()
    {
    }

}
```

Como poderia fazer pra pegar o `docblock` do método `Stack::overflow` e guardá-lo em uma variável?

Comment: http://www.phpdoc.org/ serve?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, acho que me expressei mal ou você não entendeu. Eu quero retornar o conteúdo do docblock do método `Stack::overlow` em uma string. É isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer isso através da utilização do método `getDocComment`, que está presente nas classes `ReflectionMethod` e `ReflectionFunction`.

Veja a descrição do método na [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php).

```
/**
* This is an Example class
*/
class Example
{
    /**
     * This is an example function
     */
    public function fn() 
    {
        // void
    }
}

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Example');

// to get the Class DocBlock
echo $reflector->getDocComment()

// to get the Method DocBlock
$reflector->getMethod('fn')->getDocComment();
```

No exemplo acima utilizamos `ReflectionClass`. Porém quando chamamos o método `getMethod`, uma instância de `ReflectionMethod` é retornada.

**Observação**

Vale lembrar que, para o Docblock seja capturado, é necessário que o comentário contenha dois asteriscos depois da `/`.

Exemplo correto:

```
 /**
 * @param string $value
 **/
 public function correto($value) {}


 /*
 *
 */    

 public function invalido($value) {}
```